# How do I show success message after popup closes?

Tags: javascript, html, replace, popup

I have javascript code which replace `Div` tag...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showPopup(url) {
   newwindow=window.open(url,'Image        
Share','height=490,width=850,top=200,left=80,resizable');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
      }
    function replace() {
  document.getElementById("div1").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("div2").style.display="block";
}
</script>



<div id = "div1" style="display:block" onclick = "replace()">
 123123123
 </div>

 <div id = "div2" style="display:none">454545454 </div>
```

That works but only if I do it once. If I repeat like this on the same page:

```
<!-- -------1------- -->

<div id = "div1" style="display:block" onclick = "replace()">
123123123
</div>
<div id = "div2" style="display:none">454545454 </div>


<!-- -------2------- -->

<div id = "div1" style="display:block" onclick = "replace()">
123123123
</div>
<div id = "div2" style="display:none">454545454 </div>

<!-- -------3------- -->

<div id = "div1" style="display:block" onclick = "replace()">
123123123
</div>
<div id = "div2" style="display:none">454545454 </div>
```

---

Then it doesn't work.

I have Hyperlink in `"div1"`. I want to replace it after the popup window is closed, and replace it with a success message, or disable the hyperlink after the popup opens.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because you have used the same id more than once, an id of an element can only be used once, so you will have to change the repeating elements ids to div3 and div4 etc...